# How to create Django objects so as to avoid duplicate key errors after restoring your database?

Tags: django, django-models

In Django, when you create an object, either with a Django helper function like 'create_user' or with an object's 'create' method, Django automatically creates an auto-incrementing primary key for that new object:

```
user = User.objects.create_user(username='foo', password='bar')
user.save()   # id = 1

account = Account.objects.create(user=user)
account.save()   # id = 1
```

But in the real world, if your server crashes and you have to rebuild your database server and then reload all your data, the first time you try to create a new object, you're going to get this type of error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "new-object_pkey"
```

Whenever you create a new model instance, Django seems to assume you're starting with a clean, new database and it assigns the new object an id of 1 even though, if you had to restore the database,  you already have an object in the restored table with an id of 1.

What is the "Django way" to avoid this situation with both Django's helper functions as well as the object "create" method?  I would think that this would be a common problem for any production Django website and that Django would recognize this and handle it automatically.  But I don't see such a solution discussed anywhere.  How do you avoid this situation?

**UPDATE**

I've discovered the solution.  Django does not select primary keys, your database does. In the situation I describe, you need to run Django's  'sqlsequencereset' command against your models.  I'll answer my own question in a couple of days to detail how I did this.

Comment: Nothing in this question makes sense.Django doesn't assume anything like you've said and the error is nothing to do with primary keys

Comment: That's what I alluded to in my update when I said Django does not select primary keys.  Thanks for adding a substantial comment.  :-/